# Finding Area that CGPath Intersects CGRect

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, bounding-box, cgpath

I'm working on an iOS app where I need to be able to see how much of a CGPath is within the screen bounds to ensure that there is enough for the user to still touch. The problem is, when the shape is in the corner, all the methods I would normally use (and everything I can think to try) fails when the path is in the corner.

Here's a pic:[image]

How can I calculate how much of that shape is on screen?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Do you want to measure the area (in square points) of the overlap?  Or do you want a path or mask containing just the overlap?  Or something else?

Comment: Is the CGPath completely general, or is it guaranteed to be a polygon, as shown in the diagram?

Comment: @robmayoff If possible, I would like to measure the area in square points.

Comment: @Tommy I'm not sure what you mean by "completely general" but I used the polygon in the picture to illustrate a very odd shape, which these shapes will always be.

Comment: @daveMac in the sense that a CGPath may have arcs, Beziers and a bunch of other things above and beyond being merely a polygon. However a polygon — even if not necessarily convex or even simple — is relatively easy to clip to a rectangle, which could be part of a solution.

Comment: @Tommy Well, I have considered "clipping" my shapes to a rect but they are too complex for any degree of accuracy. My shapes do have Beziers but this isn't an issue because they are fairly slight. They can just be considered straight lines.

Comment: @daveMac I'm confused by your accuracy comment; geometric clipping introduces no inaccuracies. It's a bit of a pain for complex polygons (ie, those with edges that may intersect) but I guess that isn't a concern?

Comment: @Tommy Maybe I didn't understand what you meant by "clip to rectangle"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious answers are to do it empirically by pixel painting or to do it analytically by polygon clipping.

So to proceed empirically you'd create a `CGBitmapContext` the size of your viewport, clear it to a known colour such as (0, 0, 0), paint on your polygon in another known colour, like say (1, 1, 1) then just run through all the pixels in the bitmap context and add up the total number you can find. That's probably quite expensive, but you can use lower resolution contexts to get more approximate results if that helps.

To proceed analytically you'd run a polygon clipping algorithm such as those [described here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/h/Hao-wei.Hsieh/Haowei.Hsieh/mm.html#sec3) to derive a new polygon from the original, which is just that portion of it that is actually on screen. Then you'd get the area of that using any of the normal formulas.

It's actually a lot easier to clip a convex polygon than a concave one, so if your polygons are of a fixed shape then you might consider using a triangulation algorithm, such as [ear clipping](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ear%20clipping&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGgQFjAA&url=http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf&ei=NgbIT5fuJKyr2AW44f3SDQ&usg=AFQjCNFeUbvVtF2iUgo9a3DtYRDgl2kB9w) or [decomposition to monotone edges](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=monotone%20triangulation&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CGAQFjAE&url=http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cot5520/Triangul_monotone.ppt&ei=XQbIT5j2C8fU2QXFl9SyDQ&usg=AFQjCNHpdXEIgvzPg2ZSsR6UDlIRYNqeCg) and then performing the clipping and area calculation on those rather than the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an approximation using this approach:

- Let reg be the intersection of the screen with the bounding box of the shape
- Choose N random points in reg and check if they are contained in the shape
- The area of the shape can be estimated by (area of reg)*(number of points contained in shape)/N

You can choose the parameter N based on the size of reg to get a good and fast approximation